# GraphQL, 1-1 relation mutation

Tags: node.js, graphql, graphql-js, prisma, prisma-graphql

I'm trying to implement my own GraphQL backend using NodeJS & Prisma.

For now, I just have 2 simple types:

User:

```
type User {
    id: ID! @unique
    email: String!
    address: Address! @relation(name:"UserAddress")
}
```

Address:

```
type Address {
    id: ID! @unique
    name: String!
    user: User! @relation(name:"UserAddress")
}
```

And one simple mutation, to create a user, which is resolved by:

```
async signup(parent, {email}, ctx, info) {
   return ctx.db.mutation.createUser({
      data: {email},
   })
}
```

But this doesn't work because while creating User, I omit its address. I know I should add an address field in data with the id of this user, but because we are creating it we have no access to it right now. How to fix this? (I want this to be done in the server, if possible by keeping the ! and atomicity otherwise can split into 2 mutations if that's the trick?).

Best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't plan on always providing an address when creating a new User, I'd suggest you make the address field *optional*. Otherwise, no matter how many steps you take and how fast you do it, there's **always** a moment when a potential query would return an error.

TBH, I don't even get why you'd want it to be required. I'm sure you can do without, or, if it's really mandatory, you should rather "force" the user to fill in such details when/after they register. But still, keep it optional in the schema.

If you're asking for address info at signup, the way I see it, there are 2 ways you can go about it. Either way, there would still be a single resolver. And, yeah, you may flag the **address** field as required

1. If you keep the address in the same document with the rest of the user info, things are trivial, you just write everything to the db in one query and you're done.
2. If ***Address*** and ***User*** are separate entities, still a single resolver, but more steps involved and you can can go about it in 2 ways as well:

   - You save the **user**, wait for the response to get the `id`, add the `user_id` field to the **address** and save it. After saving the **address**, you need to update the **user** by adding the `address_id` field.
   - If you're using **mongodb** there's absolutely no reason why you shouldn't generate those ids yourself. with `new ObjectId()`, add them where needed and then save the **user** and **address**. This way you could also return an optimistic response, or just wait for both operations to finish.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think for this example you are right. However, assuming I ask for its address at signup, how should I write the resolver to create an address at signup? (in one or 2 operations, with the field being mandatory or not)

Comment: I've edited the original answer, because it was too long for a comment.

Comment: Thanks, I got the point that it can't be done in one operation (assuming 2 different entities), thanks!

Comment: You can use a nested create or nested connect as described here: https://www.prismagraphql.com/docs/reference/prisma-api/mutations-ol0yuoz6go#nested-mutations